# Facing Unknown Bolt protocol version while integrationg Neo4j(Heroku) in Node js Application

Tags: node.js, heroku, neo4j, bolt, graphenedb

I am a beginner in Neo4j I have tried using the code as suggested in this documentation:
https://neo4j.com/developer/javascript/

But I am getting the following error:

```
Neo4jError: Unknown Bolt protocol version: 0

at captureStacktrace (C:\Users\abdsheikh\Documents\NodeJSApps\DrugRepo\node_modules\neo4j-driver\lib\result.js:275:15)
at new Result (C:\Users\abdsheikh\Documents\NodeJSApps\DrugRepo\node_modules\neo4j-driver\lib\result.js:66:19)
at Session._run (C:\Users\abdsheikh\Documents\NodeJSApps\DrugRepo\node_modules\neo4j-driver\lib\session.js:172:14)
at Session.run (C:\Users\abdsheikh\Documents\NodeJSApps\DrugRepo\node_modules\neo4j-driver\lib\session.js:133:19)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\abdsheikh\Documents\NodeJSApps\DrugRepo\neo4j.js:12:33)
```

**Here is my code:**

```
const neo4j = require('neo4j-driver')

uri = "bolt+s://<some-secret-url>.dbs.graphenedb.com:24787";
user = ""; //user was here
password = ""; // password was here

const driver = neo4j.driver(uri, neo4j.auth.basic(user, password))
const session = driver.session()

try {
  const resultPromise = session.run('match(c:Conditions) return c.Name');

  resultPromise.then(result => {
    session.close();
     console.log(node.properties);

    driver.close();
  }).catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
  });

} finally {
  console.log("Bye");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The error indicates that the bolt protocol might not be supported. Are you using the Neo4j version 3.5.x. I think that the new bolt+s protocol is enabled with the Neo4j 4.x series.

Try changing the uri to:

```
uri = "bolt://<some-secret-url>.dbs.graphenedb.com:24787";
```

Answer (score 1):

Ran into the same issue running Neo4j on Heroku using GrapheneDB and I actually had to downgrade `neo4j-driver` from `4.1.0` to `4.0.2` and use the `bolt` v1 protocol `bolt://` as @Tomaž Bratanič mentioned.

GrapheneDB's [documentation](https://docs.graphenedb.com/docs/nodejs) says they don't currently (June 15, 2020) support the `4.1.0` driver just yet.

You can also find more information on using the correct `bolt` versions here https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-javascript-driver/issues/595.